# Freelancer Sound Editors and Designers, how do you search your SFX when in a new studio?

Tags: soundminer, sfx, metadata

What are you using to search the SFX you bring to sessions on your drives? I have thought about Soundminer so that I may have metadata access as ProTools will only search file names and any comments written in ProTools. But I am concerned I will not be able to run the Soundminer application from the SFX drive and will need to install software on each system I go to. How are you doing it?

Comment: Soundminer is a self contained app. There's no actual installation needed. So, having it and your database on an external drive just might work. I'll try it out tomorrow and let you know.

Answer (score 7):

Soundminer has a built in function called "freelance mode" that let's you install the software and databases on the same portable drive as your library. So you can just bring the one drive, plug it in and you are ready to go. Go to the help window in Soundminer, pull up the manual and it is all explained in there.  Good Luck.

Comment: well there you go, now i don't have to run that experiment today. ;)

Comment: Testing it tomorrow before an ADR session. THX.

Comment: Totally worked.  I am in business. They even have a 30 day trial so you can test it before ponying up the pasta.  THX

Comment: For your information: Here is a manual how to setup the freelance mode in Soundminer: https://www.avosound.com/en/articles/10-simple-tricks-for-soundminer#6.-freelance-mode-(only-[smpro])

Answer (score 1):

I run AudioFinder cause it can add my Kontakt SFX patches. I do not know if Soundminer can but the old versions did not. AudioFindrer is cheaper and works very well and it can spot to Pro Tools too.

Good luck.